Back-transformation of Freeman-Tukey transformed incidence rates (in metafor)

Problem description
I am conducting a meta-analysis of recurrence rates after surgery for different treatments of the same disease using the metafor package, but I am struggling to perform the back-transformation of the estimated average outcomes to the original scale as we used the Freeman-Tukey transformed incidence rates as the outcome measure.
Code
Individual effect sizes were calculated as Freeman-Tukey transformed incidence rates using:
    ies = escalc(measure = "IRFT", add = 0, data = Data, xi = total.recurrences,
    ti = time)

We specified a three-level model to account for between- and within study heterogeneity and fit it to our different treatment groups to get a summary effect size for each treatment group.
Model 1:
     pes.sg = rma.mv(yi, vi, data = ies,
     subset = treatment == "insert subgroup", 
     random = ~1 | study.id/es.id,
     method = "REML", test = "t",dfs = "contain", 
     cvvc = TRUE)       

We also used an alternative multivariate regression parameterization for the whole dataset with our grouping variable as a moderator to obtain the same results as for the separate analyses.
Model 2:
    pes = rma.mv(yi, vi, 
    random = list(~treatment|study.id, ~treatment|es.id), 
    mods = ~0+treatment,
    data = ies, 
    method = "REML", struct = "DIAG", test = "t",dfs = "contain",
    sparse = TRUE)

We want to get the back-transformed estimated average outcomes for Model 1, or for each level of the moderator treatment for Model 2. Each with their corresponding confidence- and prediction-intervals as we would like to report the estimated average incidence rates (with their CIs and PIs) for each treatment-group on the original scale to make our results easy to interpret.
Equations
According to the documentation incidence rates $ r_i $ are calculated by escalc with $ r_i=c_i/t_i $ where $ c_i $ and $ t_i $ denote event counts and patient times, respectively.
Freeman-Tukey transformation of individual incidence rates is then done with:
$$
y_i=1/2(\sqrt{r_i} + \sqrt{r_i+1/t_i})
$$
The back-transformation of individual incidence rates is implemented  in transf.iirft with:
$$
r_i = \frac {1/t_i - 8 y_i^2 + 16 t_i y_i^4}{16  y_i^2 t_i}
$$
My questions are:

Is it possible to back-transform the estimated average incidence rates, CIs, and PIs to the original scale as intended?
If so, how would you calculate the back-transformation, and which information/which values are needed in order to do so?

I would appreciate any help on this topic.


When you fit a model, you're fitting a distribution; the inverse transform of a transform applied to data doesn't convert every aspect of the distribution back. For example, a back-transformed fitted conditional mean won't be a conditional mean. It works or sort of works for some things (like prediction intervals and simulated values) but doesn't work for moments. So it's important to be clear about what "results" you're trying to get on the original scale in order to get a fairly suitable answer. 2. I encourage you to write about your model without relying on code to explain what you did.


That is, while inverting the transform itself is reasonably straightforward  ― if $T = t(Y) =\sqrt{Y}+\sqrt{Y+1}$ then $Y = t^{-1}(T) = \frac{(T^2-1)^2}{4T^2}$ ― that may not get you to where you need. You need to be clearer about what information it is you want to get out of backtransformation.

Perhaps it's possible to separate the statistical issues from the imementation-specific ones.

This discussion on the r-sig-metanalysis list https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-meta-analysis/2017-July/000027.html may be helpful here.

@mdewey I have read the discussion and the example given by Viechtbauer and I understand that it is suggested to use the harmonic mean of the sample-sizes for the back transformation of the estimated average transformed proportion, although this procedure has been discussed controversially. However, I still do not understand how I could transfer this to incidence rates.

After reviewing the source codes of meta and metafor I think I have finally figured it out. Analogous to the back-transformation of proportions, simply the harmonic mean of the total patient times is used for the transformation of the estimated average Freeman-Tukey transformed incidence rates back to the original scale.
This way I am able to reproduce the transformed values for estimates and CIs as put out by meta.
